# Proper design for repeated timed actions

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

## Context

- Angular: 6.1.0
- NgRx: 6.0.1
- RxJS: 6.0.0

I'm creating a page where you can setup some alarms at given time, and they are repeatable (let's say you want it to ring at 10:00AM, it'll rinng at 10:00AM each day).

The feature has to:

- Be able to setup a "ring X mminutes before" for each alarm, keeping the stat of "already played" for an alarm, to change color on display for when it has ringed but it's not the time yet.
- Be able to know how much time before a given alarm rings.
- Carry other misc data for display purpose (and web notifications).

## Problem

I tried many ways of modeling this using RxJS and ended up with poor designs that always had major flaws because of my needs. Here is what I tried, and why it failed:

- Use Subscriptions, based on a tick subject that basically emits every 1 second (because precision has to be 1s).

  This is bad because I store a lot of subscriptions, and whenever I edit an alarm, I have to destroy them and recreate them from the latest database changes (not to mention it's a realtime db so updates can come from server without being made by the current client).
- Use an NgRx action that dispatches every second to trigger an effect that checks for alarms to ring.

  Again quite bad because here I'm loosing some data as I can't find a proper way to store custom data in this behavior, also makes "remaining time before alarm" monitoring quite hard.

Overall, the issue is bad design and I can't find a proper way of implementing this kind of behavior, mainly because I would like to avoid calling a method every second but on the other hand I can't seem to find another way of doing this, probably because my mind is closed on this solution, that's why I'm here afterall.

Answer (score 2):

First I would create an Alarm class that can schedule itself and contain it's state:

```
class Alarm {
  public lastRangTime = 0;
  private stopper = new Subject<void>();

  get hasRang() {
    return this.lastRangTime > 0;
  }

  get remaining() {
    return this.ringTime - Date.now();
  }

  // add more metadata

  constructor(public ringTime: number, public interval: number) {}

  start(): Observable<number> {
    return timer(this.ringTime - Date.now(), this.interval)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.lastRangTime = this.ringTime;
          this.ringTime += this.interval;
        }),
        takeUntil(this.stopper)
      )
  }

  stop() {
    this.stopper.next();
  }
}
```

And some container/service to hold all subscriptions:

```
class AlarmScheduler {
  private queue = new Subject<Alarm>();
  private subscription: Subscription = null;

  schedule(ringTime: number, interval: number = DEFAULT_INTERVAL) {
    const alarm = new Alarm(ringTime, interval);

    this.queue.next(alarm);

    return alarm;
  }

  initialize() {
    this.subscription = this.queue
      .pipe(mergeMap(alarm => alarm.start()))
      .subscribe();
  }

  destroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Than you could simply schedule alarms from `AlarmScheduler`. They will repeat themselves with given interval.

```
const scheduler = new AlarmScheduler();

scheduler.initialize();

const a1 = scheduler.schedule(Date.now() + 5000);
const a2 = scheduler.schedule(Date.now() + 10000);
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uft7up

Of course you will have to work out some details but as far as scheduling the alarms I hope the code above is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try this tomorrow (quite late here) and I'll mark as answer if it solves my issue :).

Answer (score 1):

Create [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) and run worker to check for task to run.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, timer, from} from 'rxjs';
import { withLatestFrom, map, mergeMap,  filter} from 'rxjs/operators';


class Queue {
  private queue = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);

  add(...tasks: Task[]) {
    this.queue.next([...this.queue.getValue(), ...tasks]);
  }
  remove(task: Task) {
    this.queue.next(this.queue.getValue().filter(item => item.id !== task.id));
  }
  asObservable() {
    return this.queue.asObservable();
  }
}

interface Task {
  id: number;
  at?: Date;
  period?: Date;
}

function isTimeForTask(task: Task){
  return true;
}

function runWorker(queue$){
  return  timer(0, 3000).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(queue$),
    map(([timer, queue])=>queue),
    mergeMap(queue=>from(queue)),
    filter(isTimeForTask)
  )
}

const queue = new Queue();

queue.add({id: 1});

runWorker(queue.asObservable())
  // Handle task
  .subscribe(console.log);

queue.add({id: 2});

setTimeout(()=>queue.add({id: 3}), 6000)
setTimeout(()=>queue.remove({id: 2}), 6000)
```